# Why useState is not updating immediately after button click?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to update State on click of a button, but when I am doing a console.log it is showing me the old value. Although it was updating the state as I saw in the components tab (react dev tools).

Here is my code.

```
const App=()=>{
const [test,setTest]=useState(false);

 const fun=()=>{
    setTest(true);
    console.log(test); 
   }
return(
   <>
    <button onClick={fun}>Test</button>
   </>
}
```

When I click the first time, my output is false. But when I click the second time, my output is true. I want true as output in my first click itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react, updating state is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately). Updated value is only available during the next render. Meaning, updating & them immediately console logging will give you the old state.

```
setTest(true);
console.log(test); //test is still false
```

You can print the state value to see the update -

```
return(
   <>
    <button onClick={fun}>Test</button>
    {test}
   </>
}
```